# Respawn target after destroying returns error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity3d c# to respawn an object after destroying it at a specific position. The following code returns an error message:

> Quarternion to matrix conversion  failed because input quaternion  is invalid

I get multiple spawns of the prefab a couple of seconds followed by the error message and they spawn all over the screen.

My codes as follows. For the variable respawn, I dragged and dropped the prefab from Unity itself. Thanks for any guidance.

```
    Transform initialSpawn; 
    Transform respawn;
    public static bool dead = false;

    void Start()
    {
        initialSpawn = Instantiate(respawn, new Vector3(0,7,0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
        initialSpawn.parent = transform;
    }

void Update () {
        if (dead == true)
        {
            //The line below is the one giving the error
            initialSpawn = Instantiate(respawn, new Vector3(4, 7, 0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform; 


            initialSpawn.parent = transform;
            StartCoroutine(pauseBeforeReSpawn(2));
            dead = false;
            Debug.Log("test working");
        }

 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
       if(c.gameObject.name =="barrel" || c.gameObject.name == "ground") 
       {
         Destroy(initialSpawn); 
         dead = true;
       }
    }

    IEnumerator pauseBeforeReSpawn(int seconds)  
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    }
```

This is a separate class that is killing the object:

```
public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider enter)
    {
        if (enter.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("fruit"))
        {
            ScoreCounter.counter += 10;
            Destroy(enter.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Robbert Don't just rush into editing - OP fixed their code formatting and you broke it again.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I just got a little edit crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure about the quaternion error, but for sure you are instantiating object at each frame. The pauseBeforeRespown coroutine actually doesn't nothing: it doesn't interrupt the Update itself that is still called every frame.

Comment: As far as the highlighted error is concerned could you include the line number (and note it in your code since we can't guess at the line numbering)  I've only seen that error when I rolled my own quaternion, something I don't see in your code.

Comment: I have commented the line with the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems I noticed:

1. The coroutine placement is wrong and does nothing. Or at least it doesn't do what you want it to do.
2. `Destroy()` doesn't destroy objects in the same frame. So your `Update` may get screwed up because the object is about to be destroyed yet you are still trying to change what the variable `initialSpawn` is referencing.
3. `public static bool dead = false;` This will cause all instances of this object to die horribly if you ever have more than one. You should probably consider removing `static` keyword.

I think solving the first issue will also solve the second. Here is what you could try :

```
public float respawnTimeOut = 2F;
public static bool dead = false;

private float timeSinceDeath = 0F;
private Transform initialSpawn;
private Transform respawn;

void Start()
{
   initialSpawn = Instantiate(respawn, new Vector3(0,7,0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
   initialSpawn.parent = transform;
}

void Update () 
{
    if (dead)
    {                
        if(timeSinceDeath >= respawnTimeOut)    
        {
           initialSpawn = Instantiate(respawn, new Vector3(4, 7, 0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform; 
           initialSpawn.parent = transform;                    
           dead = false;
           timeSinceDeath = 0F;
           Debug.Log("test working");
        }
        else
        {
            // Update death timer
            timeSinceDeath += Time.deltaTime;
        }
     }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
     if(c.gameObject.name =="barrel" || c.gameObject.name == "ground") 
     {
         Destroy(initialSpawn); 
         dead = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It returns the same error and the multiple spawning of the object.

Comment: In that case you need to make sure that your code that does the killing is working correctly. Could you post the bit where you kill this object?

Comment: Hi I amended the question and added the portion which is killing the object.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
       if(!dead && (c.gameObject.name =="barrel" || c.gameObject.name == "ground"))
       {
         Destroy(initialSpawn); 
         dead = true;
       }
    }
```

I'd couple this with Alex's changes, because I don't much like the look of the Coroutine in there.

Comment: You are right Steven, the !dead check will avoid repeated spawns in some situations. Good catch man :D

Comment: I added in the !dead test for the if statement. Right now it returns one error as follows: NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle UnityEngine.Object data, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)

Comment: It seems respawn is null.